# Flutter Ask about current time-related issues

Tags: flutter, dart

In Flutter, pressing once moves to the previous page of the web view, pressing twice displays a message, and pressing three times terminates the app.

The problem is that if you press the button once, the message output and the function to return to the previous page are executed at the same time.

This is my code.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

final uri = Uri.parse('https://google.com');
DateTime? currentTime;
DateTime? currentTime2;



class HomeScreen extends StatelessWiadget {
  WebViewController controller = WebViewController()
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..setNavigationDelegate(NavigationDelegate(
      onPageFinished: (String url){
        print(url);
      }
    ))
    ..loadRequest(uri);

  HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return PopScope(
      canPop: /* BOOL VALUE THAT CHECK IF ITS OK TO CLOSE APP OR NOT , YOU MAY PASS FALSE:)*/ false ,
      onPopInvoked: (didPop) {
      DateTime now = DateTime.now();



      if (currentTime == null ||
          now.difference(currentTime!) > const Duration(seconds: 1)) {
        currentTime = now;
        controller?.goBack();
      }

      if (currentTime2 == null ||
          now.difference(currentTime2!) > const Duration(seconds: 3)) {
        currentTime2 = now;
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            content: Text('Press again to exit'),
          ),
        );
      }
      else {
        SystemNavigator.pop();
        exit(0);
      }
      },
      child: Scaffold(

        floatingActionButton: Container(
          height: 40.0,
          width: 40.0,
          child: FittedBox(
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              onPressed: () => controller?.goBack(),
              backgroundColor:  Colors.grey.shade200,
            ),
          ),
        ),

        body: SafeArea(
          child : WebViewWidget(
            controller: controller,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem is only about the message output and return page running on clicking once, then it can be solved by adding a return statement in the "function to return to the previous page" part.

```
if (currentTime == null || now.difference(currentTime!) > const Duration(seconds: 1)) {
  currentTime = now;
  controller?.goBack();
  return;
}
```

But if you want to identify one click, two clicks and three clicks separately, then you would need a different strategy, because we can't be sure on first click if the user will click twice or not.

We can use a list of DateTime to log the time when back button is clicked. We will clear the list if time difference between click exceeds a threshold (1 second) so list only maintains consecutive clicks.

Detecting 3 clicks is easy this way, we just have to check if list has reached a length of 3.

Detecting first and second click is tricky, because we don't know if user will click again or not. So we will pause for 1 second to see if user clicks more, otherwise we will count the clicks and execute accordingly.

Following is the code with some more improvements

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

//not a good practice to declare variables outside of the class
//make the class stateful and declare non final variables inside the state
//and rest of them inside the widget class

// final uri = Uri.parse('https://google.com');

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  //this could also be received as a parameter in the constructor
  final uri = Uri.parse('https://google.com');

  HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List<DateTime> clicked = [];

  final clickWaitTime = const Duration(seconds: 1);

  //this could be final variable, this would get rid of null safety issues
  // uri can be passed directly
  //load request should be done in init state
  final controller = WebViewController()
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..setNavigationDelegate(NavigationDelegate(onPageFinished: (String url) {
      //print statement should be used in debug more only
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(url);
      }
    }));

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller.loadRequest(widget.uri);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      onPopInvoked: (didPop) {
        clicked.add(DateTime.now());

        //if last click is after 1 second of second last click.
        //Clear the list to reset the counter
        if (clicked.length > 1 &&
            clicked[clicked.length - 1]
                    .difference(clicked[clicked.length - 2]) >
                clickWaitTime) {
          clicked.removeAt(clicked.length - 2);
        }

        //if all clicks in list are "more than one" clicks and total 3 clicks are there
        //it means user has clicked thrice
        if (clicked.length == 3) {
          showMessage("Pressed Thrice");
          clicked.clear();
          return;
        }

        //We will wait for 1 second to check if user want to click more
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
          if (clicked.length == 1) {
            showMessage("Pressed Once");
          } else if (clicked.length == 2) {
            showMessage("Pressed Twice");
          }
          clicked.clear();
        });
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Web View')),
        floatingActionButton: SizedBox(
          height: 40.0,
          width: 40.0,
          child: FittedBox(
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () => controller.goBack(),
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
              child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: WebViewWidget(controller: controller),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void showMessage(String message) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(content: Text(message)),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. It works fine.
It seems that there are many geniuses overseas.